# $\pi$ permutation decomposed in $k$ disjoint cycles of length $n-1, \dots, n_k$. Find the order of $\pi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I'm currently working in the following excercise:

> Suppose $\pi$ is the permutation that can be decomposed in $k$ disjoint cycles of length $n_1, \dots, n_k$. Find the order of $\pi$.

I know how to calculate a permutation order but I'm not sure about the calculation of a permutation of disjoint cycles of length $n_1, \dots, n_k$ order.

Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: When two cycles are disjoint, they dont "interfeer" hence computing $\pi^{m}$ is just taking all the cycles at the power of $m$

Comment: Start with a concrete example to gain some intuition. If we have the cycles $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5)$, what is the order of this permutation?

Comment: The order of $\pi$ must be a multiple of each $n_i$ and so is the least common multiple of the $n_i$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the order of a $k$-cycle is $k$, you need $\operatorname {lcm}(n_1,\dots,n_k)$.

This is pretty much immediate, since disjoint cycles commute.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pi=C_1C_2\;...\;C_k,$ where $C_i$ are disjoint cycles of length $n_i \;\forall 1\le i \le k.$ Take any $x_i$ from each $C_i$, then by the pigeon hole principle, we have
$$x_i^{n_i}=1\; \forall {1\le i \le k}$$

Let $N$ be the lcm of $n_1,n_2,\;...\;,n_k$. Then $\exists{d_1, \; ...,\;d_k}\in \mathbb N$ such that $N=n_id_i\;\forall 1\le i \le k.$

$C_i$ are disjoint, so they are commutative. Hence $(n_1n_2\;...\;n_k)^N=1$, and thus the order of $\pi$ is $N$, the lcm of $n_1, n_2,\;...\;,n_k.$