# Length of disjoint cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't understand, whether length of a cycle in Sn is defined only for single cycles, or can we evaluate it for the product of disjoint cycles too by simply counting all the elements?

Plus, I know how the order of disjoint cycles is evaluated, but length and order of cycles are only same for single complete cycles. And I think they go different when considering disjoint cycles...

Comment: You don't simply count the number of elements. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3241974/403337).

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks for your answer. But I do understand that order of disjoint cycles is evaluated by taking lcm of order of each cycle, but I want to know whether length of disjoint cycles and order of disjoint cycles are same?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but the length of a cycle is only defined for, well, a cycle. For a general permutation there is the notion of order of an element in a group, as you noticed.

Comment: Alright Captain Lama, thanks. Well, could you please answer this one more question of mine?  If you're asked to calculate no. Of cycles of length 4 in S6, would you do it the same way when calculating no. Of cycles of order 4 in S6 ( by considering single cycles of length 4 plus the product of disjoint cycles of length 4 and 2)? Or would you simply go for no. Of single cycles of length 4? Maybe now you get my ques...

Comment: The length of a cycle is its order.  The order of a product of disjoint cycles is the lcm of the lengths.

Comment: If they say no. of $4$-cycles in $S_6$, it's just the $4$-cycles.   Btw, the answer is $\dfrac {P^6_4}4=\dfrac {6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3}4=90$.

Comment: They didn't say no. of "4-cycles". Rather I encountered 2 types of questions: 1) no. of cycles of length 4.  2) no. of cycles of order 4. BTW that formula works great when your 'n' is odd in Sn. But in case of 'n' being even, you need to go further making cases getting the same lcm(order) that's been asked(and in that case the ans comes out 180 not 90. It's even mentioned on few sites too.) I was just confused, whether I need to work in the same manner when 'length' is mentioned in place of 'order' ? Thank you.

Comment: The number of *cycles* of length $4$ is the same as the number of *cycles* of order $4$ in any symmetric group $S_n$, but that will usually be different from the number of *elements* (or *permutations*) of order $4$ in $S_n$.  Could that be where the confusion lies?

Comment: @Robert, thanks! That was literally what I was thinking but doubting.All clear now. Cheers! ^_^